# CSV email attachment also appearing inline with the message body

Tags: php, email, csv, mime, email-attachments

I read all of the similar questions here and looked at many examples on other sites.

Despite my belief that I have this setup correctly, the content of my CSV attachment is displaying inline with the body message as well as showing up as an attachment. The attachment opens and renders correctly, but the body of the message looks like this:

Report Attached

**payment_reconciliation.csv**

> Customer #,Invoice,Verifier,Post Date,Payment #,Status,Payment Date,Payment Amount
>   "456272","1395164","Verified - by Autumn on 2014-04-30 17:15:33","","135927","","2014-04-30","850.00"
>   "655469","1395163","Verified - by Autumn on 2014-04-30 17:13:17","","135926","","2014-04-30","2,275.00"
>   "351588","1395161","Verified - by Autumn on 2014-04-30 17:16:54","","135924","","2014-04-30","595.00"
>   "78444","1395160","Verified - by Autumn  on 2014-04-30 ...

Here is the portion of the code that creates the headers:

```
     $myfile = "payment_reconciliation.csv";

     $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/csv; name=\"".$myfile."\"\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$myfile."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";


   mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Anyone spot something I'm missing? Thank you.

Comment: don't build email like this use phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Comment: @Dagon. Took your advice and used PHPMailer. Also used PHPExcel. Problem solved.